# EJB with remote business interface and Client Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I've created new class library, which contains class:

```
class myData {
  private int id
  private Date date;
  private String text

  //...
  //Getters and setters
  //...
}
```

Then I've created EJB module and SessionBean with remote interface.

```
@Stateless
public class myBean implements myBeanRemote {
  @Override
  public myData getData() {
    myData md = new myData();

    //...
    //set md data;
    //...

    return md;
  }

  @Override
  public String getMessage() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

Then I use this bean in my application.

```
public class myApp {
  @EJB
  private static myBeanRemore mbr;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( mbr.getMessage() );
    System.out.println( mbr.getData() );
  }
}
```

EJB runs on GlassFish 4. Bean method `getMessage()` is working good, problem is with `getData()`. I get error: **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**.

Where is the point with my custom class `myData`? Library with `myData` is included everywhere, in Glassfish libraries too. I tried to change bean creation with `InitialContext`, but it gives the same results.

Comment: Please post more of the stacktrace - i'd bet there is more information contained

Answer (score 3):

Your `myData` class should implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.